# How do I get at the raw JSON response from a jQuery $.getJSON() request?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I get at the raw JSON response from a jQuery `$.getJSON()` request?

I just want to print the raw response in an `alert()` dialogue in my browser?

Comment: You should use something like firebug to see the raw JSON. It is way more useful than alerting something.

Comment: @alex yes I know. But this is the forerunner to a hidden text box so certain users can unhide it and copy/paste the response in an email. Long story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using JSONP, this is fundamentally impossible.

If you're sending a normal request to your domain, replace `getJSON` with `get`.

Comment: I'm not using JSONP. Tried your suggestion and I just get `[object Object]` displayed.

Comment: @Kev: Try adding `dataType: 'text'`.

Comment: After an amount of "farting about", that does work. It does mean an extra step to then parse the string to an object, but then `$.dump()` or `JSON.stringify()` is an extra step the other way.

Comment: @gertas: It is _completely_ impossible to get the raw JSONP response.  I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @SLaks: right, sorry for shortcut, I meant same-domain scenario for plain $.getJSON which OP was asking about. It is possible with jqXhr object available in 1.5. See Mario's answer. It would be nice add on to accepted.

Answer (score 15):

As of jQuery 1.5 the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object is passed in as the third argument of the callback method. The jqXHR object has a reponseText property that contains the raw JSON string.

```
function callback(data, status, jqXHR) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    // or console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is very usefull when dealing with errors : `.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.error("Response was: " + jqxhr.responseText);
        });`

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

I prefer to use the full .ajax methods so I don't have to remember the various signatures of the abstractions.

The docs tell you this is equivalent to getJSON:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

where you could have:

```
function callback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

I strongly recommend that you use Firefox and Firebug with console.log(); for this kind of thing. Alerts drive you nuts after a while.

**Edit**

Based on the other responses, I may be misunderstanding your question! You could always use Fiddler to see the raw response.

Comment: It's the raw json string that came across the wire I want to print. It was just so I could do a quick hacky debug thing to check an array value. But thanks all the same.

Comment: Firebug is the way to go then. Just change to function callback(data) { console.log(data);} to see the whole object returned.

Comment: `console.log()` still dumps the data as if it's an object, not really what I'm after. I don't get to see the raw JSON (curly braces, square brackets, field names, warts and all). Fiddler does work but I wanted to embed this in a 'secret' textbox ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `JSON.stringify()` feature in https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js.

Not ideal because it's another javascript file being loaded, but it serves my purpose.

Comment: Note that this will not necessarily return the actual JSON you received.  (The formatting may be different)

Comment: @slaks - yep but it momentarily served a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different options to get the actual response whether it be the JSON that was parsed or the error generated by the browser / server that the 'getJSON' method attempted to parse but failed.

Note: with the '.always' method the parameters change based on failure or success.

```
$.getJSON(getData.php, function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);

//As of 1.5 we have these methods:
}).always(
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //on failure
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
}).always(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { //on success
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
}).fail(
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);

//As of 1.8 we have this method also:
}).then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);}, 
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

If you want more information visit:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR or 
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/